# How to display select tag data in modal form using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I can't display my json data in the modal form. But data is coming which I can see from browser inspect. I have tried this code, can anyone one please help me.One is select form another is input field.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"catch.php",
    method:"GET",
    data:{user_id:user_id},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {   response = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show');
          $("#ven option[value="+data.vendor+"]").attr("selected","selected");
        $('#cost').val(data.repair_cost);
    }
})
  });
```